# How to BinarySearch through Array of Delegates that return true or false

Tags: c#, arrays, search, delegates

I apologize for my rudimentary question in advance. I've used this forum and others to get as far as I have. Programing level is beginner.

I'll try to be brief. I have created 266 methods that return either true or false. All 266 methods have unique equations, but take in the same parameters. I have created an array of delegates for those 266 methods, I have created a for loop to cycle through the array of delegates until "true" is returned.

After timing the for loop, (using Stopwatch), I see that it takes ~3 seconds to go through all 266 methods, if false. After some reading, I believe I need a BinarySearch to shorten the time.

I've experimented, with some examples some from this forum and the one on MSDN about the dinosaurs. But I just don't know how to write it. I understand what I need, but I don't know yet how to write it in C#.

Here is my code.

```
private delegate bool Delegate_TP_C_lt_E(string TP_direction, int TP_Start, int TP_B, int TP_C, int TP_D, int TP_E, int TP_End);
// create an array[] of delegates for TP_C_lt_E, there are 266, but we will create 267 b/c index [0] will never be used
private Delegate_TP_C_lt_E[] Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions = new Delegate_TP_C_lt_E[267];


Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions [1] = new Delegate_TP_C_lt_E(TP_C_lt_E_Ver_1);
Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions [2] = new Delegate_TP_C_lt_E(TP_C_lt_E_Ver_2);
.
.
...until
.
Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions [265] = new Delegate_TP_C_lt_E(TP_C_lt_E_Ver_265);
Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions [266] = new Delegate_TP_C_lt_E(TP_C_lt_E_Ver_266);

// my for loop
// cycle through all methods, start with 266, decrement until true, stop at 1
for (int TP_Array_Counter = (Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions.Length-1); TP_Array_Counter >= 1; TP_Array_Counter--)
{
    if ( Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions[TP_Array_Counter](TP_direction, TP_Start, TP_B, TP_C, TP_D, TP_E, TP_End) )
    {
        // I display method version... TP_Array_Counter.ToString();
        // and other stuff here...
        return true; // function found
        else return false;
    }
}

// example of one of the Functions...
// each Version has a slightly different equation
// so Ver_1 - Ver_266 are all unique
private bool TP_C_lt_E_Ver_1(string TP_direction, int TP_Start, int TP_B, int TP_C, int TP_D, int TP_E, int TP_End)
{
/* many equations, ifs, else ifs, etc... too much to paste  */
return true;
}
```

So.. yeah guys... I'm so novice that I don't know how to write the BinarySearch line of code to cycle through my functions to speed up the search...

I tried something like this...

```
Array.BinarySearch(Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions, true); \\ this compiles

// but not the stuff below
if (Array.BinarySearch(Array_of_ALL_TP_C_lt_E_Functions, true))
            return true; // getting error here
```

If someone can show me how to implement the BinarySearch into my code I would appreciate it.

Thanks
-XL

Comment: Just a thought: Have you checked if there are special equations that are very slow ? 3 secs for 266 methods seems a lot. Perhaps some optimization can be done there.

Comment: So any method may return true? Then the only way is to loop it through. If the true ones were in the end you could just check the last one.

Comment: I left out the nested for loops that lead to the if statement. Just so the question could be about how to implement the BinarySearch. But, on a side note, each of the 266 methods is tested 6 * (5^5) times, with scaling variables. So its something like  266 * 18,750 = ~ 5 million combinations. Also, the equations inside each method are a little complex.

Comment: Only 1 of the 266 methods will return true.

Comment: Have you considered using Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach? Essentially that will execute the loop across multiple threads to handle multiple iterations at the same time.

Comment: Running in parallel will only reduce execution time by number of co-processors on your computer.  The best way of speeding up is to reduce execution time of each of the 266 methods.  Post a sample of one of the methods so we can see if there is a way to speed up the processing.  If the equations are complex then using matlab may help increase speed.

Comment: Hey guys, after doing some more research, I don't think neither BinarySearch nor Parallel.ForEach will help in this case. The reason being is that each method (1 - 266) is unique. It's just labeled method "1" through "266" so I can keep track of which one the algorithm finds. It can be named {a - ZZz}, and my algorithm still has to run through each instance and check if it's "true" or "false". I was just about to start writing the binary search by hand, when I realized it makes no difference it it starts at 266/2 and then half of that and half of that, or if it starts from 1 or 266 backwards.